# Different sizes of images in Software Center

Tags: software-center

I have a question because it's strange for me that sizes of images are different in Software Center. I don't think that's normal. Can someone explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: Add in an image of the problem to make it more clear.

Comment: I can't because I still don't have 10 reputation points and I don't know what to do ;-)

Comment: Yes you can. Add in the URL and someone with 10+ rep makes it an image ;)

Comment: *Different* from what?

Comment: It's only a example: http://i.imgur.com/ChtlCnN.png